# What is the best practice for keeping files synced on local machine?

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-xp, synchronization

Working on several remote sites, and have a copy of each site on my local machine. I want to develop a library to be shared across all the sites.

What is the best way to keep several files synced on my local machine?

Working in Windows XP and PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a several possible answers here.  RoboCopy is an extremely powerful tool.  Another possibility is to create virtual directories for each of your sites, which all point to the same library folder.  That way, you only have to keep a single copy of the library on your machine.

Another possibility, if you are using a tool like Subversion, is to create a separate repository for the library files and then check out the repository into a sub-directory.  That way, you are still maintaining a single instance, but you can determine when you are going to release the library into each site.